How to retrieve a printing Job Id in .NET/ C#?
I have written an API using the PrintDocument class that sends a print job request to the printer every time I call it. Now the printing process works perfectly, however, I want to be able to track the printing progress for the case the job takes long to be completed. Ideally, after starting the printing process I would like to get back the correspondent printing Job Id that was given by the printer. That way I can later on used that id to ask for further information about the progress.
So far I am using the method Print() to start the printing process.
printDocument.Print(); // Ideally I should return the given Printing Job id

I know one way to retrieve this is using the LocalPrinterServer class after the job is stacked in the queue:
LocalPrintServer printServer = new LocalPrintServer();PrintQueue printQueue = printServer.GetPrintQueue(printerName);

// Set an undefined jobint jobId = -1;

// Get the job ID from the Queue given the unique document namePrintJobInfoCollection 
jobs = printQueue.GetPrintJobInfoCollection();
foreach (PrintSystemJobInfo job in jobs)
{
    if (job.Name == $"{documentName}_{uniqueNameId}")
    {
        jobId = job.JobIdentifier;_logger.LogInformation($"Job ID: {jobId}");break;
    }
}

However here I am looping through all of the Jobs in the queue and probably is not as efficient as if I would get immediately from the Print method.
Do you have any idea how to achieve this? I have found that there are some events such as PrintDocument.BeginPrint Event. Maybe that can be useful somehow to retrieve the Job Id? Or do I have to use directly the Print Spooler API there?

The PrintController  calls the Win API StartDoc and that api returns a non-zero value for errors or the jobId: This value is the print job identifier for the document.. The .Net implementation only checks for the error and then discards the number. The only option is to write a PrintController that re-implements  OnStartPrint and stores the result of StartDoc.
